# Laravel session clears at each request. Non persistent session. Its a nightmare

Tags: php, session, laravel-4.2

I am using laravel 4.2. After my login code, I redirect to another route for dashboard. But session is not persistent on my dashboard function

This is my code on login function

```
Session::put('email', $userObject->email); 
Session::put('firstName', $userObject->first_name); 
Session::put('lastName', $userObject->last_name); 
Session::save();
return Redirect::to('/account/dashboard');
```

if i try to print Session::all() right after Session::save(); I could get the values, But after redirection got nothing. Of course my storage path has the write permissions (0777) Session driver is 'file' Also tried with database, but no luck Any help is highly appreciated, stuck on this for a week almost.

Answer (score 0):

Issue caused because of PHP closing tag on a payment gateway library. It was included in the autoload.

Things to check if session issue comes:

1. Check for errors using debug true.
2. Check for exceptions in log file(storage folder)
3. Do not include PHP closing tag on your files. Before installing a custom library make sure that it doesnot have a closing tag or an error
4. Do not copy code from websites. if you do so, just paste it to notepad and then copy paste to your editor